# How to automatically update a version defined as a dependency in maven plugin

Tags: maven, version

I understand that maven versions plugin can be used to automatically update maven dependency versions. But I am now running into a situation that I need to automatically update the version defined in a plugin (not plugin version though). For example, I want to automatically update junit version below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>    
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <type>jar</type>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
          <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
        </artifactItem>
      </artifactItems>
```

Besides defining Junit as a dependency, is there any other way to do it?

I am hoping it can be done without defining a dependency.

Comment: First question: Why do you have defined the junit artifact for copying ?

Comment: this is just an example of a dependency to copy... maybe it is not a good example